# Counter starting after two consecutive increase of numbers R

Tags: r, dplyr, count, iteration

I have several columns, each column has the number of cases, another has the cumulative number of cases and another corresponds to the grouping variable. I want to create an extra column that starts counting after two consecutive increases of the number of cases.

Example link: http://www.filedropper.com/teste_6

Looking at the file, for hospital A the counter should start at row 60, cumulative cases are 5,7 and 10 and cases 3,2 and 3. For hospital B the counter should start at row 223 and hospital C 377.

I'm not sure how to create the counter after two consecutive increases. Should I create a loop and compare the previous value or is there a simpler way to achieve this?

I created a counter that starts at 1 but not after two consecutive increases:

```
cumulative <- dataset %>%
    group_by(hosp) %>%
    mutate(cum_cases = cumsum(cases)) %>%
    mutate(counter_cases  = cumsum(cummax(cases > 0)))
```

Comment: How do you get `1,2` for group B?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the question. How do I get a counter that starts counting after two consecutive increases? Though the B would be simpler, the `counter_cases` work for B, but not for C which is more difficult.

Comment: Shouldn't group B have all zeros for `counter` since it has only two values?

Comment: Good point @RicS. I made a mistake in my own example, but that's the idea! I added another value for B to get two increases. Thank you for noticing!

Comment: Still, there is a difference between group B and C, even if both of them increase at each step. In such cases, would you like to have only 1 zero before starting the counter (like in group B) or 2 zeros (like in group C)?

Comment: The difference doesn't matter, 1 or 100, as long as there's a consecutive increase for two days (each row is a day) I want to start the counter, sometimes there's an increase only for one day, then it stops, and increases again two or three days after it doesn't matter. I want both B and C.

Comment: What I meant is that the counter starts in the second row of group B, and in the third row in group C, even if within the groups we always have some increase in `cases`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I didn't realise that when I edited the answer. My mistake. It should be like group C. I will correct the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is inconsistent with your description, but maybe this is what you want according to your text rather than your example?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(hosp) %>% 
  mutate(counter = sign(cumsum(cases) * cases), 
         counter = counter + lead(counter),
         counter = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(counter), lag(counter), counter) == 2))
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly it! I made a mistake with the example, I need to correct it.

Comment: Actually, it's odd behaviour. The code works for some groups and not for others. I've added a link to an example dataset. These are the cases for some groups that the code doesn't work. Any clue?

Comment: @psoares I see what you mean. It needs a `cummax` added to safeguard against consecutive drops in numbers making the counter stop. I've updated.

Comment: Thank you! Though the result is not exactly what I need, it doesn't matter whether the case decreases as long as the cumulative is increase. If there are 2 cases and then 1 it's still an increase. For instance, for hospital A the counter should start at row 60, cumulative cases are 5,7 and 10 and cases 3,2 and 3. For hospital B the counter should start at row 223 and hospital C 377. I've been playing around with your code but I still don't have the desired output. Works for some but not all. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @psoares I have updated my code, and it appears to give the output you specified.

Comment: Thank you @Allan! I changed the last line to `counter_cases = cumsum(cummax(counter > 1)),` because it wasn't working for some groups. I was getting a lot of 2s. Nevertheless, I was stuck without your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, counter := cumsum(cumsum(sign(c(0, diff(cases)))) > 1), hosp]
```

Comment: Thank you! But the code doesn't do exactly want I need. I've edited the questioned and added a file with some groups to see where the counter should begin.

Comment: @psoares please link it on github as the external links are a bit scary